# Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(random.txt) returns Resource$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, resources, inputstream

Building on 1.6 SDK4

```
InputStream is = Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(R.raw.vortexrules);
```

This line is causing me no end of trouble...

My R.java shows:

```
public static final class raw {
    public static final int vortexrules=0x7f040000;
```

which tells me that the compiler is recognizing the text file and the folder and setting them as a resource.

When I run the code above, trying to set the InputStream to the text file i get:

```
07-31 01:53:58.839: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vortex.rules/com.vortex.rules.MainWindow}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040000
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2460)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1837)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4246)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040000
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:888)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:813)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:795)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at com.vortex.rules.CSV_Reader.onCreate(CSV_Reader.java:18)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at com.vortex.rules.MainWindow.CreateDatabase(MainWindow.java:103)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at com.vortex.rules.MainWindow.onCreate(MainWindow.java:39)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2407)
07-31 01:53:58.947: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19573):     ... 11 more
```

out of the LogCat.

This tells me that it can't find the resource with that ID, but it just got the ID from R.java, which is getting its information from the compiler.

I am completely lost at this point.

ANY help would be appreciated...

Comment: If your calling it as you write it in the title (Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(random.txt)) then you will get an error because you shouldn't include the file extension when loading a resource, so it'd just be 'random'

Comment: sry for the late reply, yes, I discovered that, but thnx for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as stealthcopter says in the comments, you dont need the file extension!